選挙公約に? What is this exactly?

選挙公約に知事のお墨付きを掲げられれば、一気に勝算が出てくるんです。

I understand 知事のお墨付きを掲げられば、一気に勝算が出てくるんです。 is like "if we can get the gov approval, the prospect of victory will appear"
I assume 掲げられれば is potential here and not passive?

This に is either a location marker ("in") or a role marker ("for; as"). Either interpretation gives almost the same meaning. 掲げられれば is potential + conditional.

選挙公約に知事のお墨付きを掲げられれば、...
If we can publicize the Governor's endorsement in/as/for our campaign promises, ...

